# Repeat the Entire Labeled Text upon Referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like for the text of an `item` in and `enumerate` environment to be repeated automatically upon referencing. This is similar to MS Word's cross-referencing option for inserting entire text. Can also be applicable to captions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1 ...\label{item:1}
\item Item 2 ...\label{item:2}
\item Item 3 ...\label{item:3}
\end{enumerate}

In Item~\ref{item:1} it is stated that:

\ref{item:1} <==== How to make this display the whole text of Item 1?

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dare say that this is quite difficult, without much patching

Comment: I was affraid so.

Comment: You are using `\ref{item:1}` in two separate ways, it would seem.  The first `\ref` it would seem you want a number, whereas the 2nd `\ref`, you want the quote.  Would it be OK to introduce new syntax, like `\qlabel` and `\qref` to tag and recall a complete quote? Since I don't think you want to destroy the existing functionality of `\label` and `\ref`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's best to change the list syntax a bit as latex doesn't normally save the text at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\itemtext[2]{%
\expandafter\gdef\csname item#1\endcsname{#2}%
\label{#1}#2}

\newcommand\useitemtext[2]{\csname item#1\endcsname}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \itemtext{item:1}{Item 1 ...}
\item \itemtext{item:2}{Item 2 ...}
\item \itemtext{item:3}{Item 3 ...}
\end{enumerate}

In Item~\ref{item:1} it is stated that:

\useitemtext{item:1} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Precisely! (+1)

Comment: No `\zz`? `:-)`

Comment: @egreg `\zzz_item_save_and_label:nn`

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `clipboard` package instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clipboard}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \Copy{item:1}{Item 1} ...\label{item:1}
\item Item 2 ...\label{item:2}
\item Item 3 ...\label{item:3}
\end{enumerate}

In Item~\ref{item:1} it is stated that:

\Paste{item:1}

\end{document}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]