# Referencing item in custom itemize list

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

I used [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191677/how-to-align-multiple-lines-on-same-indent-without-enumeration/191681) to create an itemize with better indentation when the text spans over multiple lines. However, I need it to support using `\label{}` and `\Cref` from the `Cleveref` package as well.

Ideally I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleverref}
\newlist{MyIndentedList}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[MyIndentedList,1]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    }
\setlist[MyIndentedList]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{MyIndentedList}
\item\label{ref1} Some text
    \begin{MyIndentedList}
       \item more text
    \end{MyIndentedList}
\end{MyIndentedList}
See \Cref{ref1} for ...
\end{document}
```

**To give:**

```
Some text
    more text

See Some text for ...
```

Hence, it should return all the text, since I do not use any kind of counter.

Comment: Erh exactly what would it be suppose to return even if it worked? Additionally, please complete your example (`\end{document}` is missing)

Comment: So, essentally, you want `\cref` to retun the whole text of the specific item you referred to?

Comment: The `cleveref` package builds on LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism. `\label`, in turn, "works" by associating its argument with the most-recently-incremented counter variable. Since you're setting up a custom `itemize` environment (which does not increment any counters) instead of a custom `enumerate` environment, `\label` has nothing to "latch on" to, and hence a `\cref`-based approach is doomed to failure. It sounds to me like what you really want is to use the `hyperref` package and its `\hypertarget`/`hyperlink` pair of macros. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to return the whole text, as @leandriis mentions. I have edited the question to clarify that

Comment: Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235609/134144 answer your question?

Comment: @leandriis Unfortunately not. I have used the past hour to try to adapt it to my case, without luck.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newlist{MyIndentedList}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[MyIndentedList,1]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    }
\setlist[MyIndentedList]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    }
\newcommand\itemtext[2]{%    
\expandafter\gdef\csname item#1\endcsname{#2}%
\label{#1}#2}
\newcommand\useitemtext[2]{\csname item#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyIndentedList}
\item \itemtext{ref1}{Some text}
\end{MyIndentedList}
See \useitemtext{ref1}{} for ...
\end{document}` should work.

Comment: Any way of having \useitemtext{ref1}{} as a clickable link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using @Mico comment - see below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newlist{MyIndentedList}{itemize}{4}
\setlist[MyIndentedList,1]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    }
\setlist[MyIndentedList]{%
    label={},
    noitemsep,
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{MyIndentedList}
\item\hypertarget{ref1}{Some text}
    \begin{MyIndentedList}
       \item more text
    \end{MyIndentedList}
\end{MyIndentedList}
See \hyperlink{ref1}{Some text}for ...
\end{document}
```